# MCRYPT extension install in Ubuntu for XAMPP

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I am using Ubuntu and installed [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). The problem is that I am getting the error

> Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH

I've tried many ways, but without success.

Comment: You need to explain much more about what you are attempting to do before you can  hope for a reasonable answer.

Comment: Dragonthoughts@let me know how can install mcrypt extension in ubuntu for lampp

Comment: With so little information, I've voted to close this question.